# Text metrics wrong when using truetype font file with Font.createFont

Tags: java, fonts, pack, truetype

I downloaded the Helvetica font from fontpalace.com (just search for Helvetica) and included it into a Java application by using Font.createFont(). But the font metrics do not work with this, i.e. the computed minimum size of a label is wrong.

A simple example application that shows this problem:

```
package fontTest;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class FontTest extends JFrame {
    public FontTest() {
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Test");
        try {
            InputStream is = FontTest.class.getResourceAsStream("Helvetica.ttf");
            Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is);
            label.setFont(font.deriveFont(12f));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        add(label);
        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FontTest fontTest = new FontTest();
        fontTest.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

If you remove the line with label.setFont(..), then the pack() command works and the window gets resized such that the text is readable. However, with this, the pack() does not work correctly, causing the label and thus the window to be resized to very tiny dimensions which cut off the text. I got this problem on Linux and Windows.

Am I missing something? It seems like some ttf font files work and some not. But I could not find a Helvetica (the original one, not the Neue Helvetica or others) that worked correctly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

font.deriveFont takes a float and not an int.
Try label.setFont(font.deriveFont(12f));

Comment: Thanks! This was an embarrassing mistake to put an int there. With the "f", the result is improved a bit, but still the metrics calculation is wrong such that the window is a bit too small and cuts off parts of the text.